# DataTemplate passing incorrect command parameter in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

I have the following in a WPF project:

**Main Window**

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateEventTesting.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ...
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.ViewModels"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.Views">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> ... </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubViewModels}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding MainContent, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding MainContent}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
                    <vw:SubView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**SubView (View for SubViewModel)**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataTemplateEventTesting.Views.SubView"
             ...
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
            <ListView.View> ... </ListView.View>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
                                           Command="{Binding PrintCurrentItemsCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is with the `SelectionChanged` `EventTrigger` in `SubView`.

`PrintCurrentItemsCommand` accepts a `ListView` as a parameter and prints a count of its items by executing the following method:

```
private void PrintCurrentItems(ListView listView)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1} items.", DisplayText, listView.Items.Count);
}
```

When I navigate from one `SubView` (where some items in its `ListView` are selected) to another `SubView`, the `SelectionChanged` event is fired on the `ListView` of the first `SubView`. This executes the `PrintCurrentItemsCommand` on the correct `SubViewModel`, but passes the new (incorrect) `ListView` as a parameter. (Either that, or the event is being fired by the new `ListView`, and the command is using the `DataContext` from the old `ListView`.)

Thus, while `SubViewModel` with `DisplayText` of "Sub1" has 2 items in its `Models` collection, and "Sub2" has 3 items, I see the following in the Output window:

```
Sub1: 2 items. // selected an item
Sub1: 3 items. // navigated to Sub2
Sub2: 3 items. // selected an item
Sub2: 2 items. // navigated to Sub1
Sub1: 2 items. // selected an item
Sub1: 3 items. // navigated to Sub2
Sub2: 3 items. // selected an item
Sub2: 2 items. // navigated to Sub1
```

Obviously the expected behaviour would be that the correct `ListView` would be passed.

The main confusion is that, for example, the command for "Sub1" is able to access the `ListView` for "Sub2" at all.

I read something about [WPF caching templates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bc0a0ed-cb98-4863-a09e-5c99d0ddf90e/mvvm-contentcontrols-view-will-not-refresh?forum=wpf), and thought I had found the solution in setting `x:Shared = "False"` on the `DataTemplate`, but this didn't change anything.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? And is there a way around it?

Comment: *"This executes the PrintCurrentItemsCommand on the correct SubViewModel"* -- Could you go into more detail about how you're confirming that?

Comment: That's based on the method printing the `DisplayText` for that ViewModel. I suppose it could be the other way around, where the event is being fired by the new `ListView`, and the command is using the `DataContext` from the old `ListView`. I will add that into the question. But either way, it seems to me that the Output window is confirming that there is a misalignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by the persistence of the `DataTemplate`.

As Ed Plunkett observed, it was the same `ListView` the whole time, and only the `DataContext` was changing. I imagine that what was happening was that the navigation took place, then the event was fired, and by this time the `DataContext` had changed - a simple property change.

In the hoped for behaviour, the old `ListView` would fire the event, and execute the first ViewModel's command, and this would occur after the navigation, hence, its items would be counted at 0. But with `DataTemplate` sharing, the first `ListView` *is* the second `ListView`, so its items are not counted at 0, they've been replaced with the items from the second ViewModel. This occurs after the navigation, so it would be expected that the `RelativeSource` would return the `ListView` with the second ViewModel as its `DataContext`.

I have managed to override this default behaviour by using a custom `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
public class ViewSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (container is FrameworkElement element && item is SubViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("subviewmodel_template") as DataTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `DataTemplate` is stored in a `ResourceDictionary` (merged in App.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.Views"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.ViewModels">
    <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" x:Key="subviewmodel_template" DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
        <local:SubView />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It turns out that in a `ResourceDictionary`, `x:Shared="False"` has the critical effect that I want it to have (apparently this is effective **only in a `ResourceDictionary`**) - it keeps the templates isolated per ViewModel.

The Main Window is now written as:

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateEventTesting.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ...
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.ViewModels"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:DataTemplateEventTesting.Views">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <vw:ViewSelector x:Key="view_selector" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> ... </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubViewModels}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding MainContent, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding MainContent}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource view_selector}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Interestingly, I found that both of the following need to be in place in this particular example:

**One**

The `DataTemplate` is in a `ResourceDictionary` with `x:Shared="False"`.

**Two**

The `DataTemplateSelector` is used.

E.g., when I satisfy the first condition, and use `<ContentControl ... ContentTemplate="{StaticResource subviewmodel_template}" />`, the issue prevails.

Similarly, when `x:Shared="False"` is not present, the `DataTemplateSelector` is no longer effective.

Once these two conditions are in place, the Output window shows me:

```
Sub1: 2 items. // selected an item
Sub1: 0 items. // navigated to Sub2
Sub2: 3 items. // selected an item
Sub2: 0 items. // navigated to Sub1
Sub1: 2 items. // selected an item
Sub1: 0 items. // navigated to Sub2
Sub2: 3 items. // selected an item
Sub2: 0 items. // navigated to Sub1
```

This is the expected behaviour, which I'd previously observed when switching between ViewModels of different types.

**Why DataTemplateSelector?**

After reading the [documentation for x:Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute), I have at least a theory on why `DataTemplateSelector` seems to be required for this to work.

As stated in that documentation:

> In WPF, the default `x:Shared` condition for resources is `true`. This condition means that any given resource request always returns the same instance.

The key word here would be *request*.

Without using a `DataTemplateSelector`, WPF has certainty on which resource it needs to use. Therefore, it only needs to fetch it once - one *request*.

With a `DataTemplateSelector`, there is no certainty, as there may be further logic within the `DataTemplateSelector` even for ViewModels of the same type. Therefore, `DataTemplateSelector` forces a *request* to be made with each change in `Content`, and with `x:Shared="False"`, the `ResourceDictionary` will always return a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing: I select an item in the right hand listview, and then change the selection the left hand listview. When the command is invoked, inside the Execute method, `! Object.ReferenceEquals(this, listView.DataContext)`. I would have expected them to be equal.

With this binding for `Command`, they were still not equal:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.PrintCurrentItemsCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
    />
```

I didn't expect much from that experiment, but it didn't take very long to try.

Unfortunately I don't have time at the moment to investigate this in depth. I haven't been able to find the source code for `System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction`, but it certainly looks as if somewhere in the flurry of events and updates accompanying the change, things happen in the wrong order.

### Resolution

The following code is almost unbearably ugly, but it behaves as expected. You could make it less ugly by writing your own behavior. It wouldn't need to be as gloriously generalized as `InvokeCommandAction`. Being less generalized, it would be less likely to misbehave the same way, and even if it did, you've got the source and can debug it properly.

SubView.xaml

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"
    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged"
    >
    <!-- snip -->
```

SubView.xaml.ds

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    var cmd = listView.DataContext?.GetType().GetProperty("PrintCurrentItemsCommand")?.
                  GetValue(listView.DataContext) as ICommand;

    if (cmd?.CanExecute(listView) ?? false)
    {
        cmd.Execute(listView);
    }
}
```

---

Slightly off topic, this would be preferable:

```
    protected void PrintCurrentItems(System.Collections.IEnumerable items)
    {
        //...
```

XAML

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
    Command="{Binding PrintCurrentItemsCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
    />
```

Code behind

```
    if (cmd?.CanExecute(listView) ?? false)
    {
        cmd.Execute(listView.Items);
    }
```

The reasoning is that a command that takes `IEnumerable` as a parameter is vastly more generally useful than one that expects any collection of items to be packaged in a listview. It's easy to get a collection of items from a listview; it's a real pain to need to have a listview around before you can pass somebody a collection of items. Always accept the least specific parameter you can without shooting yourself in the foot.

And from an MVVM standpoint, it's considered very bad practice for a viewmodel to have any concrete knowledge of UI. What if the UI design team decides later on that it should use a DataGrid or a ListBox instead of a ListView? If they're passing you `Items`, it's a total non-issue. If they're passing you `ListView`, they have to shoot you an email asking you to change your parameter type, then coordinate with you about it, then there's extra testing, etc. And all to accommodate a parameter that didn't actually need to be `ListView` at all.

Comment: With regards to the off topic, I probably should have mentioned in my question that passing a `ListView` was just for testing, in reality I will be passing the selected items collection. I concur with you on not passing a UI element to a ViewModel - though I should probably practice that in my testing too!

Comment: Thanks for the solution - you're right, it's ugly, but it works. It also confirms that I was incorrect in my initial assumption - it's the new `ListView` that fires the event.

Comment: It’s the same ListView. DataContext type doesn’t change so it doesn’t instantiate the template again. I handled the DataContextChanged event on the ListView and it was raised once when the left LV selection changed. OldValue was the previously selected left LV item, NewValue was the newly selected one. So, same ListView.

Comment: Ah, this is the main issue then. Is there any way to force the `DataTemplate` to change/refresh (I'm going to look into `DataTemplateSelector` in an attempt to do that)? There are actually other things I need to do in my project, e.g., pass and render display settings from each `SubViewModel`.

Comment: I doubt that a DataTemplateSelector will make any difference, but you may as well try it. From long WPF experience I'd advise against any moves to try to force the mysterious mis-ordering of events and binding updates to come to heel. In fact, I would advise against wasting any further time on this issue at all until you know exactly *what* is going wrong. Guessing about it is a nonproductive time sink after the first few minutes. Event handling isn't a sin; they kept it in WPF for a reason. If a roundabout indirect way to handle an event fails, but the direct way works... OK, do it direct.

Comment: ...and the only way to know exactly what is going wrong is to get your hands on the source. Which may be available; I was surprised I couldn't find it. Usually .NET reference source is easily googlable these days. Another option if you can't find the source, and cleaner than my straight event handling above, is to write your own relatively simple behavior -- maybe it just handles SelectionChanged or some such. Then if it works you're set -- and if it displays the same behavior, you can debug everything properly.

Comment: One thing I tried was creating a derived `ListView`, with a `DependencyProperty` of `SelectionChangedCommand`. I then implemented an `override` of `OnSelectionChanged` which executed that command using `e.Source` as a parameter - still the same behaviour. However, it showed the issue exists outside of `InvokeCommandAction`. The lack of refreshing the `DataTemplate` seems to be the issue, or at least would probably resolve it, so I'm going to attempt to create a new instance every time the Selector is called.

Comment: @ChrisMack Are you talking about creating a new DataTemplate dynamically? That seems like a far worse kludge than mine.

Comment: It seems to be the behaviour that I'm seeking. My app requires that the `DataTemplate` be refreshed upon each navigation, so creating a new one and (hopefully) disposing of the old one sounds like an ideal solution? The way I'm picturing it, I won't be creating actual templates dynamically, but instantiating a new instance of one template per navigation.

Comment: @ChrisMack I tried the DataTemplateSelector and behavior was identical to what you're already seeing. This is what I'm talking about with not wasting your time guessing. You're guessing at what the problem might be and then guessing at what might possibly resolve the problem you've imagined -- on the off chance that's really what's wrong. Second-order wheel-spinning. Try decompiling `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` before you spend any more time guessing.

Comment: I'd already determined that `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` was not causing the issue. However, I've managed to get it working using the `DataTemplateSelector` (I've posted the solution in a new answer)! :D

Comment: @ChrisMack How’d you determine that?

Comment: See my comment about `SelectionChangedCommand`. I created an `ICommand` `DependencyProperty` in a derived `ListView` that executed using the event's `EventArgs`, thus eliminating the need to use `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

Comment: @ChrisMack Sounds like you reproduced the issue with a different dependency property. That means you can actually figure out what the issue is. "I don't know what went wrong and I don't know why this arbitrary change fixes it" is a massive red flag in my book, but you don't work for me.

Comment: *That means you can actually figure out what the issue is.* How would you go about that? I do feel I'm fairly clear on what the issue is; I've added a bit more of an explanation to my answer. I feel I've proven that `x:Shared="False"` is the critical factor. The only thing I haven't figured out is why it is only effective in the seemingly rather far-fetched circumstances I've described, i.e. an implementation of `DataTemplateSelector`.